# export output in excel using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlwt

I want to know that how can we export our complete output in excel. I have already dig down enough. I am trying to extract symbols from text files and I want to export my output in excel. Please help. Below is my code. I tried pandas builtin funtions but it save only last value.

```
import pandas as pd

def Male():

    commas = fullstop = space = atr = openbracket = closebracket = notsign = dash = qmark = ptage = andsign = 0

    path = 'D:/Studies/Data/male/*.txt'
    inf = glob.glob(path)
    for name in inf:
        fname = name.split('\\')[-1]
        with open(name, 'r', encoding="utf8") as input_file:
            num = input_file.read()
            commas = commas + num.count(",")
            fullstop = fullstop + num.count(".")
            space = space + num.count(" ")
            atr = atr + num.count("@")
            openbracket = openbracket + num.count("(")
            closebracket = closebracket + num.count(")")
            notsign = notsign + num.count("!")
            dash = dash + num.count("-")
            qmark = qmark + num.count("?")
            ptage = ptage + num.count("%")
            andsign = andsign + num.count("&")

        df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [commas]})
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

        print(fname, "\t", commas, fullstop, space, atr, openbracket, closebracket, notsign, dash, qmark, ptage, andsign)

        df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [commas]})
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=1, startrow=1)

        commas = fullstop = space = atr = openbracket = closebracket = notsign = dash = qmark = ptage = andsign = 0
    writer.save()


Male()
```